# Version Of System.Activities.dll

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

[image]Folks,

I took over an existing wf project. The projects .NET version is 4.5 The referenced System.Activities Assembly is located in the 4.5 folder as

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Activities.dll

The version of the Assemly is still 4.0.0.0 while runtime version is v4.0.30319.

So what the heck? What version of wf4 I'm working with? How can I get the proper information?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: My copy of System.Activities.dll in that directory shows 4.0.30319.18020 as both the File version and Product version. Can you post a screenshot showing the version numbers?

Comment: Turn `Copy Local` to **on**, you'll then have the correct version (4.0.0.0).

Comment: Well, doing this, I'll achieve that the DLL will be copied to my bin folder during build. My question is, why is a 4.0.0.0 assembly located in a 4.5 folder initially?

Answer (score 1):

While I do not claim to understand the logic, I believe this is normal for .NET assemblies. Every "v4.5" System.* assembly will show version 4.0.0.0 when you look at the Properties in Visual Studio. However, when you right-click the file in Windows Explorer, and view the Properties, and switch to the Detail tab - then you should see the File and Product versions lining up with 4.0.30319.

Comment: Well, you're right. I never stumbled upon that. Thanks a lot! :-)